# SessionContext is null in Wildfly 10 Domain mode

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, ejb-3.0, wildfly-10

In Wildfly 10 standalone mode I am getting SessionContext object  using below snippet

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
UserTransaction userTrans = null;
userTrans = (UserTransaction) m_Context.lookup("java:jboss/UserTransaction");
userTrans.setTransactionTimeout(600000);
```

then in SLSB I use

```
@Resource
protected SessionContext sessionontext;
```

But same code when executed in DOMAIN mode it fails to use SessionContext as its value is null.

Update

```
@Stateless(mappedName="AppManager")
@Local(value = AppManager.class)
@Remote(value = AppManagerRemote.class)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)


    public class AppManagerBean extends AppManagerAdapter implements AppManagerRemote
    {
      try
      {
      }
      catch(Exp..)
      {
        sessionontext.setRollbackOnly();  ///Here sessionontext is null
      }
    }

    public class AppManagerAdapter
    {
        @Resource
        protected SessionContext sessionontext;
    //
    }
```

Comment: Your first code fragment does not seem to have anything to do with `SessionContext`. Please review and add more details

Comment: @SteveC updated the question. This works in standalone mode of Wildfly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SessionContext injection should be in the stateless bean itself .
So moved

```
@Resource
        protected SessionContext sessionontext;
```

from AppManagerAdapter to AppManagerBean then it worked.